# jquery events only firing on second click - why?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user page where the user lists his followers and the users he follows. If he clicks on one button, it shows the followers. If he clicks on the other button, it shows his followed users.

I don't understand the jquery event fires the second time and not the first. I set up the user "follow" lists in show.html.erb. And here is the matching show.js.erb:

```
$(function(){
    $("#trusts_list_button").click(function(){
        $("#relationship_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'follows') %>");
    });
    $("#trusted_list_button").click(function(){
        $("#relationship_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'followers') %>");
    });
});
```

Here is the show view:

```
<%= @user.name %>
<%= link_to "Add friends", facebook_friends_user_path %>

<table><tr><td>
<%= link_to "Trusts", "#follows", :id => "trusts_list_button", :remote => true%></td>
<td><%= link_to "Trusted by", "#followers" , :id => "trusted_list_button", :remote => true %></td></tr></table>
<div id = "relationship_list"><%= render 'follows' %></div>
```

After the first click, then both buttons work perfectly. But that first preliminary click really throws me off.
I would be grateful for any help; this isn't the first time I've had problems with JQuery and I'm really at a loss about fixing this sort of simple problem.

Comment: Hi Sudhir... What do you mean? Each function relates to a different item.

Comment: what's the point of `:remote => true` ?

Comment: @apneadiving I just removed :remote => true and guess what? JQuery completely stopped responding. I thought :remote => true was precisely to bring JQuery into play.

Comment: nope, `remote` is to trigger ajax queries

Comment: @apneadiving, that's interesting. Why is it that the JQuery code I have absolutely doesn't respond (not on the second click either) when I don't include it? Maybe, since I'm a noob, I'm actually using Ajax. In any case it looks like you have a lot of experience so if you have a constructive idea about the problem I would be very grateful.

Comment: `$("#relationship_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'follows') %>");` means put the content of the `follows` partial in my dom element, can't see any server request there. hence no ajax needed => no `remote`. I can't debug it, you should dive in your js console to check if there are any errors

Comment: Can you provide the show action code?

Answer (score 0):

first thing.. IDs should always be unique.. you have two element with the same id.. so chnage that

```
...
<%= link_to "Trusts", "#follows", :id => "trusts_list_follows_button", :remote => true%></td>
<td><%= link_to "Trusted by", "#followers" , :id => "trusted_list_followers_button", :remote => true %>
....
```

then call your click event for each button

```
$(function(){
  $("#trusts_list_follows_button").click(function(){
    $("#relationship_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'follows') %>");
  });
  $("#trusted_list_followers_button").click(function(){
    $("#relationship_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'followers') %>");
  });
});
```

Problem that you had in your code was, the click event was for the same buttons .. since your selector was `$("#trusted_list_button")` . this selects  the button whose `id=trusted_list_button` which in your case is for both the buttons.. so the click event was firing for the second button only...

Comment: Hi Bipen, thanks for this but the first element is "trusts_list_button" and the second is "trusted_list_button". IT's a bit confusing so I changed the names, but the problem is persisting. Maybe I misunderstood your comment?

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix try this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#trusts_list_button").click(function(){
        $("#relationship_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'follows') %>");
    }).click();
    $("#trusted_list_button").click(function(){
        $("#relationship_list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'followers') %>");
    }).click();
});
```

When `doc ready` happens it clicks for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced this problem, and I determined that there was an event existing on the cloned element - but I couldn't find or remove the event (although I knew it was there)... click 1 - nothing, click 2 - fired normally, click 3 - fired twice (sort of)

My solution was to clone the specific offending element again and use the clone (without cloning events this time) to replace the original.

$(el).replaceWith($(el).clone());